# compoentWillReceiveProps setting default value after I am changing the value using react-redux-form

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, typescript

I have my form in which I am setting some default value when the form is loaded and I have a react-select dropdown which renders a dropdown with some default value. I have a `Form Component` which is being render in `Create` and also `Update` forms. So whatever default values I want I am passing it as props in the `Update Form` and I have an `Input` Component which render the Input box i.e. react-select dropdown. I am catching the default values passed in `Update Form` and sending it as a `defaultValue` prop in the Input component and I am setting this as initial value using the `componentWillMount()` now whenever I am trying to update the select input value It automatically setting it self to the default value.

I know this is because I am receiving the props in Input component and setting it in `componentWillMount` method.

When a new value is being selected I am calling handleSelect in the and updating the state of the value and then I am dispatching an action manually to set that value as value of my particular model now what is happening here in that when I am dispatching the action it is calling an state change that I think rerendering my Input component.

I am unable to figure out a solution.
Any Help Would be appriciated.

**Following is my code**

**Input Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Select} from 'react-select';
export interface IInputProps {
    initialValue: string;
}

export interface IInputState {
    value: string;
}

export class Input extends React.PureComponent<IInputProps, IInputState> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { value: '' }
    }

    handleSelect = (val: string) => {
        this.setState({
            value: val
        })
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const { state: { value } } = this;
        const { initialValue } = nextProps;
        if (initialValue && initialValue !== value) {
            this.setState({
                value: initialValue
            });
        }
        dispatch(actions.change("exampleForm.value", initialValue));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Select
                required
                value={this.state.value}
                placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : 'Select...'}
                options={menuItems}
                onChange={this.handleSelect}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

**Form Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Input } from './Input';
export interface IFormProps {
    defaultValue: string
}

export class Form extends React.PureComponent<IFormProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Input
                initialValue={this.props.defaultValue}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

**Update Form Component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {Form} from './Form'

export interface IUpdateFormProps {
    username: string;
}

export class UpdateFormImpl extends React.PureComponent<IUpdateFormProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Form
                defaultValue={this.props.username}
            />
        )
    }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        username: state.get('username')
    }
};

export const UpdateForm = connect<{},{},IUpdateFormProps>(mapStateToProps)(UpdateFormImpl)
```

Comment: Just trying to understand the code a bit. It looks like you are looking for `defaultValue` as a prop coming in from the input. But your input component only has the prop of `initialValue`.  In `componentWillReceiveProps` you are pulling `defaultValue` which looks to me like it will be undefined.

Comment: Edited the code a little bit.. it's initialValue in the nextProps also.. sorry 